# Sharepoint 2013 add SSRS 2008 reports

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have almost no knowledge on Sharepoint and there was a contractor who set up bunch of SSRS 2008 reports on a sharepoint site. Now that he left and I just joined this company and now I am given a task to add some new SSRS reports to the site.

In the visual studio (BIDS) I can see the TargetServerURL is already set to the Sharepoint site and TargetReportFolder, TargetDataSourceFolder etc all have been set to the site/project. So I have successfully modified some reports and deployed successfully. I have the Sharepoint admin account I think. This part is very similar to deploy reports to a report server.

The Sharepoint site when loaded is like below.

[image]

When I create a new report in VS and deploy it I can see it under the project folder of the sharepoint site. The project folder in this case is EEReports.

[image]

The report I added is Report1, so if I open EEReports folder I can see and run it. It seems all the reports are from this folder, but not every report in this folder is on the same domain.

[image]

But if I go to the default page, the newly added report is not there. So what do I do? I guess there must be some work need to be done to add the report to the default site.

Comment: "I know there must be plenty of books out there it's just I don't have time for these now. I need to get it work asap, thanks." - yeah, well that's not how the world works!

Comment: Yes you are right but just wondering what you would do if you were on my position. I got books right here, but most contents are not particular related. I will work on books in my spare time but not in projects.

Comment: The user clearly states that has zero knowledge and doesn't have time to read a book, wants the community to give a long answer and make his work.

Comment: @Macr Climent: I want to be an astronaut but alas I don't "have time to read a book"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right figured out with some luck. Just click Edit on the page, create a new list item for the new report, high light the item and select Insert - Link - From Sharepoint from the top menu. Then I can pick up the new report deployed from BIDS.